# how to run selective modules from a directory using nosetests?

Tags: python, nose

I have multiple modules in same directory and i'm running the below nosetests command:
nosetests --processes=2 --process-timeout=1500 -v --nocapture -a=attr --attr=api --exclude-dir-file=src/tests/externalapi/test_p0_security_tests.py --with-xunitmp

No luck tests in test_p0_security_tests.py still executed.

Comment: Could you describe a little more what should happen with your command? To skip some tests with nose you can use a decorator https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures.

Comment: I  want the test methods in test_p0_security_tests.py to be skipped by nosetests

Answer (score 0):

`nosetests` does not support `--exclude-dir-file` by default. Since you are not reporting getting an error about the option being invalid, and there is only one plugin I know that provides this option, I'm assuming you are using the [`nose-exclude`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-exclude) plugin. `--exclude-dir-file` takes for value a *file that contains a list of directories to ignore*. Passing the name of a module to ignore is not the correct use for it.

At any rate, there's the `--ignore-files` option which does take a regular expression. The regular expression appears to be matched against the *base name* of the test file rather than the full path. `--ignore-files=test_p0_security_tests.py` should do it. (If you want you can escape the dot because it is a wildcard, but I usually don't bother.)